# common element in html

Tags: html, css

I am developing a project and find that there are elements that are common to all pages, I wonder if there is any way to define these elements generally and call them from your html to avoid having to define each of the pages. thank you very much for your help

Comment: shared CSS or shared HTML or both?

Comment: You can do it with server-side languages such as [`PHP`](http://www.php.net) or ASP.NET etc.

Comment: The only way to do using plain html is to either use an Iframe, or javascript by using an Ajax Request. Otherwise you'll have to go with a server-side language as Itay mentioned

Comment: server-side is the way to go.  Don't do this in JavaScript - you'll be reducing the accessibility of the page.

Answer (score 0):

*test.html*

```
<div>Menu</div>
```

When you need to have this menu, just call this code in your page:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
   alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Another option could be [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), or just something like includes with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to do exactly this with pure HTML, but by mixing in a little server side script, you can. Just to give you an idea what it would look like:

This example uses PHP. If you are on a Microsoft server, you would need to translate this example into .NET or .aspx.

---

First, save the following to a file called "mytest.php" in the same folder as your other pages. (You can put it in a subfolder if you wish, but for this example I will keep it simple).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just one line for this test. A little useless, but you can see the point.

Now, in the `<head>` tag of your HTML, you can do this (I added the `<head>` tags just so you can see it... You would not want to have TWO sets of `<head>` tags.)

```
<head>
    <?php include 'mytest.php'; ?>
</head>
```

Now, visit the page and display the HTML and you should see that line incorporated into your HTML. Note that any document that contains PHP code (as above) must end with a `.php` extension.

Comment: not want to call the server to display these items, as they are simple menus and think it's much faster to place them in the html, thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As @loops suggested, I would highly recommend [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for the rescue.

It's a great MVC framework built with JavaScript and no external dependencies.

It offers the possibility to create custom elements using their [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

So you could create a new element `<mymenu></mymenu>` and you can give this new tag some behaviour as well as bind events to it.

AngularJS takes care of all the rest and your new tag will be available across all the pages of your application.

And yes, you are correct thinking that should be done on the client side rather than server side.

I am happy to provide a full working example for you once you get your head around the framework first. Otherwise I think it will be too much information at once ;)